# How to optimize query which has or in left join clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

When I execute my code, it spends many hours and it has not been finished. And I know that the problem is using 'or' in left join clause. So I want to know how to rewrite this code that is can be executed.

```
SELECT  WFTD.RELA
            , WFTCS.PARENT_TASK AS CONSULT_TASK_ID
            , WFTCS.CREATE_DATE AS CONSULT_DATE
            , WFTD_THIS_TASK.APPROVED_RESULT_DATE AS THISTASK_APPROVED_RESULT_DATE
FROM TNH_WF WF
INNER JOIN TND_WF_TASK WFT ON WFT.WF_ID = WF.WF_ID AND WFT.OWNER_ATONEMENT IS NOT NULL AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06', 'N07')
INNER JOIN TND_WF_TASK WFTCS ON WFTCS.WF_ID = WFT.WF_ID AND WFTCS.WORK_TRAY_ID = 'N07' 

LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD_THIS_TASK ON WFTD_THIS_TASK.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID AND WFTD_THIS_TASK.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'

LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD

ON (
            (
                (WFTD.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.PARENT_TASK 
                AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N07') 
                AND WFTD.CONSIDER_RESULT_CODE LIKE '%Consult%') 
            
            OR 
                (WFTD.NEXT_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID 
                AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06')) 
            AND 
                WFT.STATUS IN (0,1,2)
            )
        
        OR 
        (WFTD.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID 
        AND WFT.STATUS IN (3)))
    
    AND WFTD.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'
```

Comment: Are you sure the reason of this performance issue is the `OR`? How did you find this out? A standard approach to avoid this is to use two separate queries and to combine the results with `UNION ALL`. But I doubt this is clever in this case. I also doubt your analysis is correct. For example, I guess the `LIKE` condition within your join clause can be very slow.

Comment: If that is the logic you need then you don't re-write the code (because rewriting the code would change the logic to something else). If you want to improve performance then add indexes, use materialized views, gather statistics, swap to faster hardware, reduce network latency, etc. Some of that is outside the scope of StackOverflow and for others you would need to provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements for your tables and an `EXECUTION PLAN` for the query.

Comment: You could consider using `AND INSTR(WFTD.CONSIDER_RESULT_CODE, 'Consult') > 0` and then put a function-based index on `INSTR(CONSIDER_RESULT_CODE, 'Consult')` but you would need to check the `EXECUTION PLAN` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: This is called `semi-cross join`. These are usually very hard to optimize. IMHO you should try to create a virtual column having some `CASE` in it. Create index in this column/expression and try to "simplify" the query, join on this column. But I'm not sure whether this will applicable in your case.

Other option would be to split this `OR` into multiple JOINs and then UNION their results.

Comment: `WFTCS.WF_ID = WFT.WF_ID` -- Join a table with itself using the PK? There's no need; just one instance will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
in this optimized query i did following things:

 1. I've separated the JOIN conditions into separate LEFT JOIN clauses
    to improve readability.
 2. I've simplified the WHERE clause by using an explicit check for
    WFTD.WF_TASK_ID IS NOT NULL OR WFT.STATUS = 3 instead of the complex
    condition in the original query.
 3. Make sure proper indexing is in place for the join columns and the
    columns used in WHERE conditions for optimal performance.

    SELECT  
    WFTD.RELA,
    WFTCS.PARENT_TASK AS CONSULT_TASK_ID,
    WFTCS.CREATE_DATE AS CONSULT_DATE,
    WFTD_THIS_TASK.APPROVED_RESULT_DATE AS THISTASK_APPROVED_RESULT_DATE
FROM 
    TNH_WF WF
INNER JOIN 
    TND_WF_TASK WFT ON WFT.WF_ID = WF.WF_ID 
        AND WFT.OWNER_ATONEMENT IS NOT NULL 
        AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06', 'N07')
INNER JOIN 
    TND_WF_TASK WFTCS ON WFTCS.WF_ID = WFT.WF_ID 
        AND WFTCS.WORK_TRAY_ID = 'N07' 
LEFT JOIN 
    TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD_THIS_TASK ON WFTD_THIS_TASK.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID 
        AND WFTD_THIS_TASK.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'
LEFT JOIN 
    TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD ON WFTD.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.PARENT_TASK 
        AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N07') 
        AND WFTD.CONSIDER_RESULT_CODE LIKE '%Consult%'
        AND WFT.STATUS IN (0, 1, 2)
        AND WFTD.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'

LEFT JOIN 
    TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD_NEXT ON WFTD_NEXT.NEXT_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID 
        AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06') 
        AND WFT.STATUS IN (0, 1, 2)
        AND WFTD_NEXT.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'
WHERE 
    (WFTD.WF_TASK_ID IS NOT NULL OR WFT.STATUS = 3)
```

Comment: I don't think you will observe a good performance as long as you keep this ugly `LIKE` condition

Answer (score 0):

While we can't be certain without seeing your execution data, it is very likely due to your join to `WFTD`, as you've rightly guessed. There are a number of approaches to deal with this. From least rewrite to greatest:

1. Add a `/*+ USE_CONCAT */` hint to the query block (right after the `SELECT` keyword at the top). That may push Oracle into rewriting your query for you as a series of `UNION` (or `UNION ALL` followed by a `DISTINCT` sort) blocks, each with a definite equijoin condition to eliminate the `OR` conditions. But as you have some compounding and `IN` operators as well, Oracle may struggle with it. Worth a try as it'd require no change to the code other than the hint.
2. *If* the join to `WFTD` is a 1:1 join (at most only one row from `WFTD` could possibly match *any* of the possible join conditions), you can simply join to the table three times and then take the columns you need from whichever found results:

   ```
          SELECT  COALESCE(WFTD1.RELA,WFTD2.RELA,WFTD3.RELA) AS RELA
                      , WFTCS.PARENT_TASK AS CONSULT_TASK_ID
                      , WFTCS.CREATE_DATE AS CONSULT_DATE
                      , WFTD_THIS_TASK.APPROVED_RESULT_DATE AS THISTASK_APPROVED_RESULT_DATE
          FROM TNH_WF WF
          INNER JOIN TND_WF_TASK WFT ON WFT.WF_ID = WF.WF_ID AND WFT.OWNER_ATONEMENT IS NOT NULL AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06', 'N07')
          INNER JOIN TND_WF_TASK WFTCS ON WFTCS.WF_ID = WFT.WF_ID AND WFTCS.WORK_TRAY_ID = 'N07' 

          LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD_THIS_TASK ON WFTD_THIS_TASK.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID AND WFTD_THIS_TASK.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'

          LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD1 ON WFTD1.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.PARENT_TASK 
                                            AND WFTD1.CONSIDER_RESULT_CODE LIKE '%Consult%'
                                            AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N07') 
                                            AND WFT.STATUS IN (0,1,2)
                                            AND WFTD1.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'

          LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD2 ON WFTD2.NEXT_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID 
                                            AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06')
                                            AND WFT.STATUS IN (0,1,2)
                                            AND WFTD2.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'

          LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD3 ON WFTD3.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID 
                                            AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06')
                                            AND WFT.STATUS IN (3)       
                                            AND WFTD3.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'
   ```
3. Lastly, if Oracle was unable to rewrite it for you with the hint and the join to WFTD might *not* be 1:1 (which could result in row expansion [too many rows] in the option #2 above), then you can rewrite the whole query with `UNION`. Copy paste it three times joined by `UNION`, collapsing the join to one of the three in each one:

   ```
        SELECT  WFTD.RELA
                    , WFTCS.PARENT_TASK AS CONSULT_TASK_ID
                    , WFTCS.CREATE_DATE AS CONSULT_DATE
                    , WFTD_THIS_TASK.APPROVED_RESULT_DATE AS THISTASK_APPROVED_RESULT_DATE
        FROM TNH_WF WF
        INNER JOIN TND_WF_TASK WFT ON WFT.WF_ID = WF.WF_ID AND WFT.OWNER_ATONEMENT IS NOT NULL AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06', 'N07')
        INNER JOIN TND_WF_TASK WFTCS ON WFTCS.WF_ID = WFT.WF_ID AND WFTCS.WORK_TRAY_ID = 'N07' 

        LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD_THIS_TASK ON WFTD_THIS_TASK.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID AND WFTD_THIS_TASK.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'

        LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD ON WFTD.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.PARENT_TASK 
                                        AND WFTD.CONSIDER_RESULT_CODE LIKE '%Consult%'
                                        AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N07') 
                                        AND WFT.STATUS IN (0,1,2)
                                        AND WFTD.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'
        UNION
        SELECT  WFTD.RELA
                    , WFTCS.PARENT_TASK AS CONSULT_TASK_ID
                    , WFTCS.CREATE_DATE AS CONSULT_DATE
                    , WFTD_THIS_TASK.APPROVED_RESULT_DATE AS THISTASK_APPROVED_RESULT_DATE
        FROM TNH_WF WF
        INNER JOIN TND_WF_TASK WFT ON WFT.WF_ID = WF.WF_ID AND WFT.OWNER_ATONEMENT IS NOT NULL AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06', 'N07')
        INNER JOIN TND_WF_TASK WFTCS ON WFTCS.WF_ID = WFT.WF_ID AND WFTCS.WORK_TRAY_ID = 'N07' 

        LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD_THIS_TASK ON WFTD_THIS_TASK.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID AND WFTD_THIS_TASK.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'

        LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD  ON WFTD.NEXT_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID 
                                          AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06')
                                          AND WFT.STATUS IN (0,1,2)
                                          AND WFTD.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'
        UNION
        SELECT  WFTD.RELA
                    , WFTCS.PARENT_TASK AS CONSULT_TASK_ID
                    , WFTCS.CREATE_DATE AS CONSULT_DATE
                    , WFTD_THIS_TASK.APPROVED_RESULT_DATE AS THISTASK_APPROVED_RESULT_DATE
        FROM TNH_WF WF
        INNER JOIN TND_WF_TASK WFT ON WFT.WF_ID = WF.WF_ID AND WFT.OWNER_ATONEMENT IS NOT NULL AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06', 'N07')
        INNER JOIN TND_WF_TASK WFTCS ON WFTCS.WF_ID = WFT.WF_ID AND WFTCS.WORK_TRAY_ID = 'N07' 

        LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD_THIS_TASK ON WFTD_THIS_TASK.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID AND WFTD_THIS_TASK.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'

        LEFT JOIN TND_WF_TASK_DETAIL WFTD ON WFTD.WF_TASK_ID = WFT.WF_TASK_ID 
                                          AND WFT.WORK_TRAY_ID IN ('N02', 'N03', 'N06')
                                          AND WFT.STATUS IN (3)       
                                          AND WFTD.POL_COV_FLAG = 'P'
   ```